# PIL Remove noise around the plotted dots drawn by draw.ellipse

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I plotted some dots on a white image by using draw.ellipse in PIL

```
 draw.ellipse((x[i][j] - 2, y[i][j] - 2, [i][j] + 2, [i][j] + 2), fill='black', outline='black')
```

((x,y) is a coordinate of the plot)

Then I found some noise around the plots like this:

[image]

How can I get rid of them?

Add
The size of the original white image is 315*207, the size of the plot is 4*4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you save the image as a JPG file?

JPG compression creates noise surrounding features (including your dot).

Comment: Yes I did! Oh I see. It's not like I'm sticking to JPG but is there any way to save image as a JPG file without creating the noise?

Comment: JPG is inherently lossy. If you want to avoid noise, you can use PNG.

Comment: I just saved it as BMP and it worked well. I don't see any noise anymore. Thank you so much

Comment: PNG files should have much smaller file size, while maintaining the same quality as BMP. They're the best choice for text, plots and line art.